# How to determine if a website uses an internal WAF?

Tags: webserver, waf

Is there a tool to know if a website uses a firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple tools for WAF detection. The problem is that they are not much efficient / reliable. They can do the basics.

e.g.: wafw00f is a WAF detection tool.